# Linking AWS Route 53 domain to EC2 Load Balancer to resolve to another Route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

Right now I have two domains registered in Route 53: exampleABC.com and ex.com.

1. exampleABC.com routes to an Elastic IP connected to an EC2 instance. Works.
2. I want ex.com to route to the same instance so that a user going to "ex.com" is directed to "exampleABC.com.
3. I set up an Elastic Load Balancer and Target Group whose registered target is the EC2 instance for exampleABC.com (the target group is connected to the ELB).
4. I created an A record Alias in "ex.com" Hosted Zone that targets the ELB.

Not sure what to do after this. My thought is that ex.com should now route to exampleABC.com, but the site loads forever without going anywhere.

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Had to create an S3 bucket for "ex.com" and redirect traffic to "exampleABC.com" then add an A-record alias in "ex.com" that pointed to the S3 bucket.